# req.params not passed in middleware

Tags: node.js, express

I am trying to read and pass req.params to another middleware. But I am getting an empty object in response.

```
var app = require('express')();
app.get('/foo/:bar', function(req,res, next) {
  console.log('1 --', req.params);
  next();
});
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  console.log('2 --', req.params);
  res.end();
})
app.listen(3000);
```

I am hitting this url -

> http://localhost:3000/foo/hello

Output I am getting is -

```
1 -- { bar: 'hello' }
2 -- undefined
```

How to pass req.params to another middleware?

Answer (score 1):

```
//route
app.get('/foo/:bar', yourMiddleware, function(req, res) {
  res.send('params: ' + req.params);
});

//middleware
function yourMiddleware(req, res, next) {
  console.log('params in middleware ' + req.params);
  next();
}
```

Comment: this ones a better option, besides one can also use ```res.locals._params``` to set for one request-response cycle.

Comment: Hi Thalaivar, thanks for your response. But, your solution will work for only a specific route. I want req.params to be passed to my middleware for all the routes.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, `req.params` is only available in handlers that explicitly set a parameter.

So this works:

```
app.get('/foo/:bar', function(req,res, next) {
  console.log('1 --', req.params);
  next();
});

app.use('/foo/:bar', function(req, res, next) {
  console.log('2 --', req.params);
  res.end();
});
```

If you don't want that, you need to keep a reference to the params in a different property:

```
app.get('/foo/:bar', function(req,res, next) {
  console.log('1 --', req.params);
  req.requestParams = req.params;
  next();
});

app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  console.log('2 --', req.requestParams);
  res.end();
});
```